# Fourier cosine integral of a piece-wise function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, self-learning

I am trying to learn PDEs by my self these days, because I need it for my personal projects; Thanks everyone helped me with my self-learning since yesterday.
I'm not sure my answer is correct for the following question; I would appreciate if you check it for me :)

 
I want to find Fourier cosine integral of:

\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(x) & 0\leq x \leq \pi \\
0 & x>\pi
\end{cases}

$$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty A(\alpha)\cos(\alpha x)d\alpha = \int_0^\pi A(\alpha)\cos(\alpha x)d\alpha+\int_\pi^\infty A'(\alpha)\cos(\alpha x)d\alpha
$$

$$
A(\alpha)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx
$$

$$
A'(\alpha)=0
$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Where did $A'(\alpha)=0$ come from?

Comment: It's because the function is 0 for $x>\pi$